# _OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryBase", referenced from: objc-class-ref in GDataServiceGoogle.o

Tags: objective-c

i want to integrate yahoo api in iphone app, but i getting this  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryBase", referenced from:objc-class-ref in GDataServiceGoogle.o error, Please Help me how to get rid of from this error.

Comment: That looks like a Google API and not for Yahoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once check in your project that frame was present or not for that once check this one,

Make sure you actually linked the framework to your target application. In xcode , click the project file, click your desired target, select the build phases tab, expand link binary with libraries. If you do not see the framework you are trying to use, then click the plus at the bottom of that section navigate to the framework and add.